# Installed Python to portable python

Tags: python

I have installed python from .msi installer in windows and installed a lot of other modules. i would like to have all these available on a portable thumbdrive, but i don't want to redownload all the extramodules. Is there a way i can convert my C:\python26* to a portable python installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is pretty smart about knowing where it is run from. What happens if you just copy the whole directory tree to the thumb drive?